# data integrity when interrupts are too fast

Tags: interrupt

I have an encoder that fires ~54000 interruptions per second.
This is way too fast for my arduino uno.
But I'm trying to see what I can get from it anyway. For science.

```
unsigned long tickACount = 0;
unsigned long tickBCount = 0;

void myInterrupt(){
  tickACount++;
  tickBCount++;
}
```

Then in my main loop, every second I print `tickACount` and `tickBCount`.
I can see my arduino is able to handle only about 2050 interrupts per second. No surprise here.

What surprises me, is that `tickACount` and `tickBCount` have different values! `tickBCount` is consistently higher that `tickACount`.

Ok now I switch them to volatile. And according to the documentation, volatile only makes sense for 8bit values. The counts will eventually overflow but it doesn't really matter. I just want to see if those two variables are still different.

```
volatile uint8 tickACount = 0;
volatile uint8 tickBCount = 0;

void myInterrupt(){
  tickACount++;
  tickBCount++;
}
```

The result is that the two values are still different.
Also, wrapping them into some `ATOMIC` macro does not help.

From what I read, interrupts cannot be interrupted. 
And beside, if my interrupt was aborted midway, then `tickACount` would be higher than `tickBCount`, not the other way around.

Therefore, what can be the explanation for those two variables to be different?

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: They are the same. But when you print one and then print the other one, there has been interrupts between that. Make a full sketch that shows the problem. With a lot optimizations, the uno board might do more than 54kHz interrupts, perhaps 100kHz. Interrupt tutorial: https://gammon.com.au/interrupts

Comment: You can save quite a few CPU cycles by creating your own ISR instead of relying on the one from the Arduino core to call your interrupt handler. See [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/8926), section _Write your own ISR_.

Comment: If you want simple counter, why don't you use Timer1 or Timer2 with external clock source?

Comment: Would you consider using extra hardware to reduce microcontroller load?  How about using shift registers to count pulses.

Comment: I was convinced that 54kHz is way to fast for Arduino, which runs at 16MHz. That's only ~300 cycles per interruption + it has to handle the normal loop.
I replaced my interrupts by the Encoder library https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Encoder, and it now seem to work fine. I digged a bit into that library, it seems to do about the same thing as I did, but in assembly with probably some big optimization done.
Well done, about the `tickCountB` > `tickCountA`. The possibility of `tickCountB` being incremented during the 2 prints hasn't come to my mind. I guess that's experience!

Answer (score 3):

> 54000 interruptions per second [...] is way too fast for my arduino
>   uno

Your test is probably flawed. My Uno does handle that interrupt rate
with no issues. See my test code below.

> my arduino is able to handle only about 2050 interrupts per second

You are probably doing something wrong, like blocking interrupts for too
long, or using a library that does so.

> What surprises me, is that `tickACount` and `tickBCount` have
>   different values!

As previously stated in comments, this is not the case. Instead, the
counters have been incremented while you were printing them.

> And according to the documentation, volatile only makes sense for 8bit
>   values.

Either the documentation is grossly wrong, or (most likely) you have
misread it.

> From what I read, interrupts cannot be interrupted.

This is indeed the default behavior. You could change it, by issuing
`interrupts()` within the interrupt handler, or by declaring an ISR as

```c++
ISR(XXX_vect, ISR_NOBLOCK)
{
    ...
}
```

but that is seldom done.

Below is my test code. I used Timer 2 to generate a square wave on
pin 3, which is both a PWM pin (OC2B) and an interrupt pin (INT1).
The PWM frequency is about 54.054 kHz.

```c++
const uint32_t PRINT_PERIOD = 1e6;  // print counts every second

struct TickCounts {
    uint32_t tickA;
    uint32_t tickB;
};

volatile TickCounts rawCounts;

void myInterrupt() {
    rawCounts.tickA++;
    rawCounts.tickB++;
}

// Atomically read both counts.
static TickCounts getCounts() {
    TickCounts counts;
    noInterrupts();
    counts.tickA = rawCounts.tickA;
    counts.tickB = rawCounts.tickB;
    interrupts();
    return counts;
}

void setup() {
    // PWM at 54 kHz on OC2B = PD3 = INT1
    DDRD  |= _BV(PD3);    // pin PD3 as output
    OCR2A  = 37 - 1;      // period = 37 * 0.5 us = 18.5 us
    OCR2B  = 37/2 - 1;    // duty cycle ~ 50%
    TCCR2A = _BV(COM2B1)  // non-inverting PWM on OC2B
           | _BV(WGM20)   // mode 7: fast PWM, TOP = OCR2A
           | _BV(WGM21);  // ditto
    TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22)   // ditto
           | _BV(CS21);   // clock at F_CPU/8 = 2 MHz

    Serial.begin(9600);
    attachInterrupt(1, myInterrupt, RISING);
}

void loop() {
    static uint32_t last_time_printed;
    if (micros() - last_time_printed >= PRINT_PERIOD) {
        last_time_printed += PRINT_PERIOD;
        TickCounts counts = getCounts();
        Serial.print(counts.tickA);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.println(counts.tickB);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
54053 54053
108107 108107
162161 162161
216215 216215
270269 270269
324324 324324
378377 378377
432431 432431
486485 486485
540539 540539
...
```